# What are the exact steps to use aws api gateway client certificate with a spring boot mvc rest controller?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-api-gateway, client-certificates

I developed a basic **Spring Boot 2.0 / Java 8** application that I would like to secure with a **AWS API Gateway certificate** and to make sure that only the AWS API Gateway can call this back end service.

Here are the steps I followed

1. I generated a client certificate in AWS API Gateway
2. I selected the client certificate in my API stage and validated
3. I clicked on copy and pasted the content of the client certificate into `certificate.pem`
4. I converted the PEM certificate into a DER encoded certificate using `openssl x509 -outform der -in certificate.pem -out certificate.der`
5. I used keytool to import the DER encoded certificate into a JKS keystore using `keytool -import -alias tomcat -keystore keystore.jks -file certificate.der -storetype JKS`
   I input *password* twice and keytool displays this message 
   `Certificate was added to keystore`
6. I moved `keystore.jks` to `src/main/resources/`
7. I edited `application.properties` to add those settings

   - server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
   - server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.jks
   - server.ssl.key-store-password=password
   - server.ssl.key-alias=tomcat

When I am starting the Spring app this error message is `Alias name [tomcat] does not identify a key entry`

Reading the same error message on stackoverflow I understand that I certainly miss the private key here and that I need to add it to the keystore.
Listing the entries in `keystore.jks` displays tomcat alias as a trustedcertentry and not a privatekeyentry.

Can someone guide me through the process or explain me what I am missing here to use **AWS API Gateway client certificate with a Spring Boot app** ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: For mutual SSL, you must use the `server.ssl.trust-store` options to configure which clients (AWS) your server trusts. See https://dzone.com/articles/hakky54mutual-tls-1